# Use of unresolved identifier 'CameraViewController'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I get this error, how I could fix it?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipgedtenxjzsm7q/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-04-26%2020.07.52.png?dl=0

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'CameraViewController'
```

I am using https://cocoapods.org/pods/ALCameraViewController

Code:

```
  import UIKit

class pantalla6: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

//    "Mes 1", "Mes 2", "Mes 3", "Mes 4", "Mes 5", "Mes 6", "Mes 7", "Mes 8", "Mes 9", "Mes 10", "Mes 11", "Mes 12"

    var tableData: [String] = []
    var tableImages: [UIImage] = []
    var tableControl: Int = 0
    var guardaImagen: UIImage?
    var indexPathSelected : Int = 0

    //NSUSERDEFAULTS // guardar estado
    var objetoNsDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var stringsarraydeimagenes:[String]?
    var key = "keySave" //Se guarda el nombre de las imagenes en esta key

    //FIN NSUSERDEFAULTS


    //var CeldaSwipeada: Int = 0




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let croppingEnabled = true
        let cameraViewController = CameraViewController(croppingEnabled: croppingEnabled) { image in
            // Do something with your image here.
            // If cropping is enabled this image will be the cropped version
        }

        presentViewController(cameraViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        //USAR SWYPE START


        //self.collectionview.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPathSelected).addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


        //USAR SWYPE FIN

        collectionview.delegate = self
        imagePicker.delegate = self             /// estableces que el delegado va estar en este viewcontroller


        //RECUPERAR IMAGENES
        //tableImages = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("ImagenesGuardadas")

        /* LO QUE YO HABIA PUESTO
        if let testArray : AnyObject? = objetoNsDefault.objectForKey(key) {
        var readArray : [NSString] = testArray! as! [NSString] //falta saber donde se guardar las imagenes tableImages es del tipo UIimages
        }
        */

        //LO QUE TU HABÍAS PUESTO
        /*
        let placesData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImagenesGuardadas") as? NSData


        tableImages = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(placesData!) as? [UIImage])!
        */




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {return UIInterfaceOrientation.Landscape.rawValue}



    func guardardatos(){

        /*LO QUE PUSISTE
        let placesData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(tableImages)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(placesData, forKey: "ImagenesGuardadas")

        */

        //save
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(stringsarraydeimagenes, forKey: key)
        defaults.synchronize()

        /*
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tableImages, forKey: "ImagenesGuardadas")

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        */
        print("dato guardado")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: colvwCell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colvwCell
        cell.lblCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.imgCell.image = tableImages[indexPath.row]


        /*quitando esto se ve mejor*/

        cell.basurita.hidden = false
        cell.imgCell.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        cell.basurita?.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")


//        cell.basurita?.addTarget(self, action: "deleteUser:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


        //let action = #selector(self.deleteUser)

        //cell.basurita.addTarget(self, action: action, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        cell.basurita?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(pantalla6.deleteUser(_:)),
                                 forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        /*quitando esto se ve mejor*/

        // Remove the button from the first cell
        /*if (indexPath.row == 0){
            let close : UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UIButton
            close.hidden = true
        }
*/

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
        indexPathSelected = indexPath.row


        //pantalla8fotoViewController().newImage = tableImages[indexPathSelected]
        let loginPageView =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FotosID") as! pantalla8fotoViewController
        loginPageView.newImage = tableImages[indexPathSelected]
        self.presentViewController(loginPageView, animated: true, completion: nil)


        //loginPageView.newImage = tableImages[indexPathSelected]
        print("pasado")
        print(indexPathSelected)
       // print(loginPageView.newImage)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!     /// defines el UIImageView

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()   ///  defines el image Picker




    @IBAction func openLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {        ///accion del boton Library

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated:true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func openCamera(sender: AnyObject) {        ///accion del boton Camara



        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera



        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated:true, completion: nil)

    }

    //Mark: delegates    //// delegado del imagePicker controller que establece que una imagen fue escogida ya sea de la camara o del carrete

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {


        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            //picture.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            //picture.image = pickedImage



            tableImages.append(pickedImage)
            tableImages.insert(pickedImage, atIndex: tableControl)

            tableData.append("Mes  " + "\(tableControl + 1)")
            //tableImages.insert(pickedImage, atIndex: tableControl)
            //tableImages[tableControl] = pickedImage
            //tableData[tableControl] = "Mes  " + "\(tableControl + 1)"

            guardaImagen = pickedImage

            if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)

            {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(guardaImagen!, nil, nil, nil);
            }
           // arraynsuserdefault = tableImages


            collectionview.reloadData()
            tableControl += 1
        }
        //NO ESTA EN EL TUTORIAL

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    // metodo tambien del delegado que detecta si se presiono cancel en el picker

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func deleteUser(sender:UIButton) {

        let i : Int = (sender.layer.valueForKey("index")) as! Int
        //tableData.removeAtIndex(i)
//        tableData = nil
        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"cup.png")!
        tableImages[i] = image
        //tableControl--
        collectionview.reloadData()

    }

    func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancelar(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }


    @IBAction func BorrarFotos(sender: AnyObject) {
        tableImages.removeAll()
        tableData.removeAll()
        tableControl = 0
        collectionview.reloadData()

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code & the error message directly in the question, instead of providing a link to a screenshot?

Comment: yes, it already ready

Comment: now, I get the error:
pantalla6.swift:10:8: No such module 'ALCameraViewController'

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of issues that cause this problem.

1. You didn't import ALCameraViewController at the top of the file that you are calling the ALCameraViewController object. The [README.md](https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController) doesn't tell you to do that, but it necessary in order for your project to recognize it.
2. You don't have Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2. Some of the syntax is different from Swift 2.1 to 2.2. So make sure that you have your OS, Xcode program, and Swift language updated.